# Uri.https on Flutter is limiting the length of my url

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a get request to Firebase. In my url, I have to send the auth token which is very long (more than 900 characters). I create the url this way:

```
 var url =
     Uri.https('firebaseio.com', '/mydb.json?auth=$authToken&orderBy="userId"&equalTo="$userId');
```

But the url is not complete when I print it (the last characters are always lacking) and hence the request does not work. Anyone knows a solution for that?

Comment: Just wondering why the auth token is 900 characters long?

Comment: I have no ideia :( It is created by Firebase.

Comment: True removing the last double qoute from `equalTo=$userId');`. The one directly before $userId

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  Does it help if you use `Uri.parse` instead of `Uri.https`?  Note that `Uri.https` expects the second argument to be a path and for query string parameters to be supplied via its optional `Map` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL isn't actually being cut. The `print` function can have a limit on its line length when being using in Flutter. Look elsewhere for your issue.

It likely has something to do with your misuse of quotes within your string. It's not normal to have quotes in your query parameters that are opened but not closed.

You can also improve this code by using the optional third `queryParameters` parameter of the `Uri.https` constructor to handle your query parameters:

```dart
var url = Uri.https(
  'firebaseio.com',
  '/mydb.json',
  {
    'auth': authToken,
    'orderBy': '"userId"',
    'equalTo': '"$userId"',
  },
);
```

Comment: @MoniqueSchreiner Just out of curiosity, could you elaborate on why the query parameters didn't work? I do have double quotes in the parameters.

Comment: Because it changes the " to %22

Comment: Indeed it was a problem with the quotes. The queryParameters didn't work because I need the double quotes in the URL. But the real problem was I didn't close the last double quotes... So, the correct way is: final url = Uri.parse(...orderBy="userId"&equalTo="$userId"'); I also changed it to Uri.parse.
I am recommenting so you can see the part I changed

Comment: @MoniqueSchreiner Have you tried printing it after you do the parse? You should see it does the same thing as using the query parameters. You can do it however you choose, I just personally strongly prefer using the query parameters map with Uri.https as I find it to be better coding style with an identical result.